# StartSwing Gui not always visible

Tags: java, swing

When starting a `javax.swing.JFrame` after setting some buttons everything is visible when `setVisble(true)` is used.
Button click works (text label change), hoover messages can be seen for the buttons...

However when I try to initialise something else right after the method used for the `JFrame` the GUI is not visible.

Is there anything I should be aware of when starting a `swing` GUI with threads in the background ?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear without the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question, however if you are trying to run code that includes, for example, a 'while' loop on the same thread upon which you created your GUI, it will essentially block the GUI.

You should therefore create a new thread for any background logic or operations which may be causing the GUI to freeze.

Comment: thanks for that. Actually that was the problem. I fiddled a bit around it but than found a invoke later method which did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> However when I try to initialise something else right after the method used for the JFrame the gui is not visible.

If you add components to a visible GUI then the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The above code will invoke the layout manager. Otherwise the size of the added components is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Comment: not sure if that helps me. I added the code how I create the gui. is there something wrong ?